# Java でShift-JIS からUTF-8へ変換する方法

Tags: java

初歩的な質問です。私持っている現在の元のファイルはSJISです。それで、Linux画面で日本語の漢字を表示したいんです。
自分が書いた現在のJavasソースコードは：

```
private static String convertUTF8ToShiftJ(String uft8Strg) {
    String is = null;
    String shftJStrg = null;

    try {
        byte[] bt = uft8Strg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        is = new String(bt, "SHIFT-JIS");
        shftJStr = new String(is);
        logger.info("Converted to the string :" + shftJStrg);
        System.out.println(shftJStrg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return uft8Strg;
    }

    return shftJStrg;
}
```

で、Linux画面で表示された結果は：

```
*** UX0025.SH ﾂ開ﾂ始ﾂ　ﾂ（startedﾂ）
*** UX0025.SH ﾂ偲�ﾂ行ﾂ陳�ﾂ（executing...ﾂ）
*** UX0025.SH ﾂ終ﾂ猟ｹﾂ　ﾂ（endedﾂ　ﾂ）
```

ただ、実際に表示したい結果は：

```
*** UX0025.SH 開始　（started）
*** UX0025.SH 実行中（executing...）
*** UX0025.SH 終了　（ended　）
```

私のコードがどこに間違っているのかよくわからなくて困っています。
誰かがわかっている方いませんか。助かります。

Comment: ソースは UTF-8からShiftJISに変換しているように見えますが、ShiftJISからUTF-8に変換すればよいのではと思いました。

Comment: お疲れ様です。ちなみに、ゲットとアウトプットの文字列を変えてみてましたが、駄目でした。

Comment: convertUTF8ToShiftJ()だけでなく、ファイルを読み込んでいるコードとconvertUTF8ToShiftJ()の結果をファイルに書いたり画面に出したりしているコードもたいへん重要です。

Comment: 引数の utf8strg は UTF8の文字列ですか？もしそうならなにもせず println() で表示するとどうなりますか？

Comment: ちなみに、 utf8strgはSJISのはずです。パラメータを変えてプロセスを変えてみても結果ほぼ同じです。

Comment: Javaには「SJISのString」というものは存在しません。Stringは常にUnicodeです。

Comment: uft8Strパラメータがutf16として渡されているようです.自分のコンセプトが間違っているような気がします。直してみています。

Answer (score 2):

提示されている `convertUTF8ToShiftJ()` は、Unicodeの文字列を入力として、それを UTF-8 のバイト列にエンコードし、それをシフトJISとして無理やりデコードしてUnicodeに戻しています。ASCII以外の文字は壊れるでしょう。

Javaの`String`は常にUnicodeですので、

- ファイルを読むときにストリームをシフトJISとしてデコードするよう指定する
- ファイル出力や画面出力のときにストリームにUTF-8としてエンコードするよう指定する

以上で期待する動作になると思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: @int32_t このコンテキストで Unicode と書いちゃうのは誤解を招くっす。 UTF-16 なら正確。